# Did anyone receive a video attached to the weekly newsletter for Unix.SE?

Tags: discussion, stackexchange

This is something strange. I received a video attachment in this weeks newsletter of Unix.SE that is received every Tuesday.

The subject was 'Unix & Linux Weekly Newsletter - Tuesday, December 3, 2013'
The video attached was [Why are Bad words bad] www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dd7dQh8u4Hc

Don't think Gmail added that ;). Didn't see any relevance with the video and unix.se newsletter. Have anyone else received it? Was it on purpose?

---

Update: Think that was not from the mail. But seeing it with the mail only with this newsletter.

Screenshot: 
[image: video down the newsletter]

Comment: Can you forward a copy of the newsletter to me, please? anna@stackexchange.

Comment: @AnnaLear When trying to forward the mail, the video is not getting attached. So, it seems it was not with the mail. But I see this issue only with this newsletter. Such video is not attached to any other mail in my mailbox either. Screenshot added to the post.

Comment: That's... odd. Are you running any browser extensions? Are there any Youtube links in the questions you were sent (maybe Gmail is going something clever with content?)? I'm pretty certain that this video isn't from us, or at least not deliberately inserted into the newsletter.

Comment: I do have http://gmelius.com/ extension that affects the Gmail interface. Don't think that is adding it, as it is meant to 'Remove Ads' :). Will try to check by disabling it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a popular question on Unix.SE this week.

[How do I get a websites title using command line?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/103252/how-do-i-get-a-websites-title-using-command-line)

It contains a YouTube link points to "Why Are Bad Words Bad?".

I assume the newsletter selected this hot topic on Unix.SE.

When Gmail processed the newsletter email, it auto generated a video preview for the link.

[YouTube Previews - Gmail Labs graduation and retirement](http://gmailblog.blogspot.hk/2010/02/gmail-labs-graduation-and-retirement.html)

Comment: That seems to be answer here. :)